# How can I quickly check if my sprite tiles well?

Tags: sprites, tilemap, tools, workflow

I am trying to create tilemap sprites that tile nicely, but checking how well they tile is really cumbersome.

Ideally, I'd like to have an image editor that shows a layout like this, so I could see if it tiles well without a manual check:

```
     [img]
[img][img][img]
     [img]
```

What programs can do this, or how can I otherwise make this easier?

Comment: I think you're talking about checking if texture tiling works seamlessly. And gimp at least to my knowledge has a render->map or something function that does that. but not while editing. Otherwise, wally has this feature, but its damn old. (half life texture editor)

Comment: http://www.amnoid.de/ddsview/ supports tiled preview of many image formats. And which image editor are you using? I'm sure it has some way of tiling an image.

Comment: Which editor are you using? It should be possible to hack something together using Photoshops smart objects

Comment: Set it as your desktop background, and choose the "Tile" option.

Comment: "What programs can do this"

Krita can do this and it even lets you pant while wrapped (see answer below)

Answer (score 67):

Here's a quick hack that works with any image editor.

If your tile image is called `tile.png`, create an `index.html` like this:

```
<body style="background:url(tile.png) repeat 0 0"></body>
```

<sup>(Thanks [@Deryllium](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/52588/deryllium) for the simpler alternative!)</sup>

Open that in a web browser.

Whenever you need to check how well the image tiles, save it, and refresh the web browser.

[image: the workflow]

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)'s *export* shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and [Chromium](https://www.chromium.org/)'s *refresh* shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>. The <kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>r</kbd> are adjacent on a QWERTY, so this is pretty fast to do.

Comment: Very inventive! You can also make the HTML simpler by using `<body style="background: url(tile.jpg) repeat 0 0;">`

Comment: @Deryllium I edited to use that instead. It's not only simpler, but also more robust to differences in [user agent stylesheets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet), and shows more repeats. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any time! Glad I could help.

Comment: You can also add <header><meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2"></header> right before the <body> to make the page auto-load every 2 seconds.

Comment: Or, if you were so inclined, you could go deeper and set up a tool like grunt or gulp to watch for changes and live-reload the browser when you make them.

Comment: Which makes me wonder, why the heck don't image editors have a "tile to infinity" option?

Comment: @Kroltan [ddsview](http://www.amnoid.de/ddsview/) reportedly has a dedicated "tile view". [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)'s flood-fill tool can read from the clipboard, which is also fast to test with with.

Comment: @Anko True, but my point was for an actual, editable, and fully functional tiled view. These tools make it faster, but not a seamless process (unintentional pun).

Comment: @Kroltan Look at Krita (KritaUser00402050's answer) for editable and fully functional tiled view. It's fantastic. This is a good answer for those stuck with one tool that doesn't have the feature, but there should be more upvotes on the "use Krita!" answer.

Comment: this is way more work than necessary.  just apply the image as tiled wallpaper on your desktop...
no new programs.
no copy/paste, copy/paste, copy/paste, etc

Comment: tools like grunt or gulp (admittedly have no clue what they are, but with that said, i am sure i've surmised correctly), may very well be excellent.  but, sounds like what's being offered could be solved even more easily by using a little bit of simple ajax.  not only would you not need to learn another new tool, but you wouldn't have to create a meta refresh tag either!  once you have that ajax thing built...just build a quick server-side script to deliver the answer.  much more elegant, and it's more useful in the long run.  you could actually reuse this idea in real-world projects!

Comment: i wasn't able to add this into the last comment, so I apologize for the double post.  but, i thought it pertinent to include a link to an ajax guide to accompany my previous rant:
[link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)

Answer (score 18):

Using photoshop or GIMP, you can use the offset command. If you are working for say a 100x100px image, you can offset it 50px in each direction, and the seam where the image tiles together will be displayed in the middle of the image.

This page has screenshots demonstrating how this works: http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2015/01/how-to-create-a-seamless-pattern-tile-in-photoshop.html

Comment: As an added bonus, now the seam is right in the middle of the image, for quick and easy editing!

Answer (score 17):

Krita has a feature that allows you to edit tiling textures and see the changes update live. By pressing the W key, it enables wrap around mode, which makes this possible. A youtube video of this feature in action is available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FaG4JLiqP3M). (feature is enabled at 0:12)

Comment: This deserves more upvotes. Its a bit of software that does exactly what is asked for in one button press. 
Better yet, it also lets your painting to wrap around too - which is almost certainly going to help anyone making seamless textures.
You should also point out Krita is free and can be downloaded;
https://krita.org/download/krita-desktop/

Comment: +1 If someone has the same question, *this* is the first answer they should see. "What programs can do this?" "Krita".

Answer (score 6):

Make your tile a tiled wallpaper on you desktop. Super easy and no coding or extraneous software.

Comment: +1 This works [*spectacularly* well](http://i.imgur.com/iMloeIS.gifv) on Linux with `inotifywait -m -e modify --format '%w' tile.png | while read file; do feh --bg-tile "$file"; done` running. Just save the image; wallpaper changes immediately. Also works with multiple files specified in addition to `tile.png`. When I don't need fullscreen, this rocks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to test multiple images, it may help to have an mini webapp based on Anko's answer. This will let you drag images onto the page to let you test them in quick succession:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  document.body.addEventListener('dragover', function(event) {
    // Accept the drag
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  document.body.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {
    // Prevent page redirect
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e) {
      // Set background image
      document.body.style.background = 'url(' + e.target.result + ') repeat 0 0';
      document.body.textContent = ''; // Remove instructions
    };

    // Begin reading file
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.dataTransfer.files[0]);
  });
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  border: 2px dashed black;
}

body {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag an image here</p>
```

Comment: Another very intuitive answer. You could create a chrome extension or create a Node.js / Electron desktop application using this.

Answer (score 0):

In GIMP: Filters -> Map -> Tile. If you change the unit to "%" and then enter 300% x 300% for the dimensions, you'll get a 3x3 tiling of your image, which lets you see all four edges easily. After doing it once you can use Ctrl-F (repeat last filter) to re-do the tiling after making modifications, as long as you don't use any other filters of course.